# jquery dialog() - catch only div very next to the opener

Tags: jquery, dialog

I'm trying to set up multiple dialogs in the same page, trying to open only the one next to the opener
es.

```
<ul>
  <li class="dialog">
     <a class="opener" href="#">1</a>
     <div class="modal" title="Title for 1">Content for 1</div>
  </li>

  <li class="dialog">
     <a class="opener" href="#">2</a>
     <div class="modal" title="Title for 2">Content for 2</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

and jquery:

```
    $(".modal").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        zIndex: 3999,
        modal: true
    });


    $('.opener').click(function() {
        $(this).next().dialog('open');
    });
```

but $(this).next().dialog('open'); always gives me undefinded!
where do I fail? :(
thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to keep a reference to the dialog, like this:

```
$(".opener").each(function() {
  $.data(this, 'dialog', $(this).next());
}).click(function() {
  $.data(this, 'dialog').dialog('open');
});
$(".modal").dialog({
  autoOpen: false,
  zIndex: 3999,
  modal: true
});
```

[You can test it out here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/mbdjt/).  The reason you do this is because when you call `.dialog()`, it moves the newly wrapped element to the end of the body, just before `</body>`....so it's no longer the next element.

Comment: ok! so I understand why next dosn't work... thanks! but it still does not catch the div... should i think about numbering them? Is that i wanted to make the code a bit simple...

Comment: @nobody - you could certainly do that, have the `href` point to the `<div>` it goes with, for example `href="#divID"`, the in the click handler you can  use your original code, just replace `$(this).next().dialog('open');` with `$(this.hash).dialog("open");`.

Answer (score 0):

If there is just one div in each li then you can use find().

```
 $(this).parent().find("div")
```

will give you the div inside the li that was clicked